# Manually set track listen count in Banshee?

Tags: banshee

How can I manually edit the track play count for a track for Banshee?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. From the Ubuntu Software Centre install the SQLite Data Browser

   ```
   sudo apt-get install sqlitebrowser
   ```
2. Navigate to `~/.config/banshee-1` in the file browser (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to toggle the viewing of hidden `.` files)
3. Right click on `banshee.db` and click on *Open With Other Application*. From here open the *Use a custom command* box and enter `sqlitebrowser`
4. From within the SQLite Data Browser then click on the *Browse Data* tab, and then click on the *CoreTracks* 'table'.
5. From here scroll horizontally so you can see the track names. Once you've found a track scroll even further to the right until you find the *PlayCount* header. Double click on the current playcount, enter a new one, and press *Apply Changes*

*Note: Banshee's developers have [expressed some interest](http://mail.gnome.org/archives/banshee-list/2008-September/msg00186.html) in implementing this from within Banshee, if you [remind them](http://banshee.fm/about/contact/) they might jump into action...*

[image: Screenshot of various steps]

---

Linked Q&A:

1. [Manually Sync Play Counts in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/99098/manually-sync-play-counts-in-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

If you're importing your music library for the first time, it is useful to set PlayCount to 1 for all the files. This way if you add any music, you will find it in the automatically generated playlist "Unheard".

To do this, click on the *Execute SQL* tab and paste the following code:

```
UPDATE CoreTracks SET PlayCount=1;
```

Then click on *Execute query* and you're done.