# Manually Sync Play Counts in Ubuntu

Tags: 10.10, banshee, sync

I am following the advice located at this link to manually change the playcounts in Banshee by altering the database: [Manually set track listen count in Banshee?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14795/manually-set-track-listen-count-in-banshee)

But it is too time consuming to individually change the play counts for every track in a playlist. Can someone give me the line of code I need to  update every track with a given value (ex. year=85) to a certain play count number (ex. play count= 5).

Answer (score 2):

Certainly.

Once you have `sqlitebrowser` installed and connected (see [Manually set track listen count in Banshee?](https://askubuntu.com/q/14795/6161)), go over to the 'Execute SQL' tab and run something like:

```
UPDATE coretracks SET playcount = [__] WHERE [field] = [value] AND [field2] LIKE [value2];
```

example:

```
UPDATE coretracks SET playcount = 10 WHERE title LIKE '%Bach%';
```

You can get a list of the fields that are available by clicking the + next to 'CoreTrack' on the 'Database Structure' tab.

If you are not familiar with the SQL language, the above statement is saying: `update` make a change `coretracks` to the table named CoreTracks.  Change each row where `title` has a value that contains `Bach`.  The change to make is to change the `playcount` field to a value of `10`.  If you have something specific in mind, I'd be happy to help with the SQL.  Put a comment below.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution:

**Step 1:** MP3's have a "BPM" tag that I find virtually useless (who's in the mood for songs at 117 BPM only?)  Anywho, in iTunes/Rhythmbox/whatever you're importing from, sort your songs by play count, select all that have play count X, and change the BPM to X. Rinse and repeat.

**Step 2:** Use SQLite Library Browser (as above), but this time, in the "Execute SQL" tab,  type

```
UPDATE coretracks SET playcount='1' WHERE BPM='1'
```

Again, simply rinse and repeat.

I recently did this for my 15,000 song library.  Step 1 took about 30 minutes, but Step 2 took about 30 seconds. Enjoy!