# How do I find and delete duplicate music tracks?

Tags: 11.10, banshee, music, duplicate-files

My issue is that for some reason I have duplicates of some music tracks. However they are not named identically. For instance:

> Music/Prefuse 73/One Word Extinguisher/07. Detchibe.mp3

&

> Music/Prefuse 73/One Word Extinguisher/07 - Detchibe.mp3

Notice they are duplicate songs but the 07**.** & the 07 **-** is tricking duplicate file finders that search based on file names.

Comment: Have you tried any of the suggestions [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/3865/how-to-find-and-delete-duplicate-files)?

Comment: Can fdupes single out one of the two duplicates and delete it? Otherwise the fdupes -r command only generates a list which doesn't get me anywhere.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I find duplicate songs?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4323/how-can-i-find-duplicate-songs)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `fdupes` like the answer for question [»How to find and delete duplicate files«](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3865/how-to-find-and-delete-duplicate-files) suggested. Let me give an example:

```
mkdir -p "Music/Prefuse 73/One Word Extinguisher/"
dd if=/dev/urandom of=Music/Prefuse\ 73/One\ Word\ Extinguisher/07.Detchibe.mp3 bs=1023 count=2048
  2048+0 records in
  2048+0 records out
  2095104 bytes (2.1 MB) copied, 0.379806 s, 5.5 MB/s
cp Music/Prefuse\ 73/One\ Word\ Extinguisher/07.Detchibe.mp3 Music/Prefuse\ 73/One\ Word\ Extinguisher/"07 - Detchibe.mp3"
fdupes -rd .
  [1] ./Music/Prefuse 73/One Word Extinguisher/07.Detchibe.mp3
  [2] ./Music/Prefuse 73/One Word Extinguisher/07 - Detchibe.mp3

  Set 1 of 1, preserve files [1 - 2, all]:
```

First I created the directory like in your example. The I made a file from random data and copied its contents to another files. When I run `fdupes -rd` the software finds the two exact files and asks which one to delete.

If you have lots of files, you can use the option `-1`. `fdupes` will print all duplicates on a single line. You can process them with `xargs` and other shell features.

Comment: Can the out put from the fdupes -r command be piped to the mv command?

Comment: fdupes -rd is close to what I want but I'll have to press one about 2000 times for all the dupes to be gone.

Comment: I added a paragraph to my answer above.

Comment: The issue here is that `fdupes` does not seem to dive into sub folders. For instance `~/Desktop/Dupes2/` has a folder in it titled Blood Sugar Sex Magik with the Dupes, yet a simple `fdupes -r` command doesn't return any list.

Answer (score 2):

I found a somewhat simple command chain. Much thanks to @Oli.

```
fdupes -rf --quiet ~/Desktop/Dupes2/ | while read i; do mv "$i" ~/Desktop/Dupes/ ; done
```

This used `fdupes` to recursively (`-r`) find  the dupes, omitting the first (`-f`). Bash reads this line by line through `read` amd hands each line to `mv` to move all duplicates to another directory. Note the use of quotes in the `while` loop to handle spaces and other dodgy punctuation that `fdupes` will not handle (even with `-1`/`--sameline`).

Comment: @Oli, this isn't doing the trick. No files are being moved from one folder to the other

Comment: @Oli see my latest comment to "qbi" below.

Answer (score 1):

In the answers to [Manually set track listen count in Banshee?](https://askubuntu.com/q/14795/6161), it describes how to get at the database that banshee uses to save all track information.

Once you're connected to the database, on the execute query table, paste

```
select tweaked_track, count(*) from 
  (select replace(replace(replace(title, ' ', ''), '-', ''), '.', '') as tweaked_track 
   from coretracks) 
group by tweaked_track 
order by 2, 1 desc;
```

into the SQL string box, then click 'execute query'.  This will show you all the tracks you have with the same title ignoring spaces, dashes, and periods.  If there are other characters you want to ignore, add them to the query in the same pattern. (IE add `replace(` before the first existing "replace" and after the last ")" on that line, add `, '[character you want removed]', '')`.

(I don't know how much you know about sql - if you need more details, post a comment.)

This will give you a list of titles.  You will have to actually do the delete yourself.

There may be a better way of doing this, but if there is, I don't know about it.

Once you have a big list of files to be deleted (either from my method or from `fdupes` like others have mentioned), put the list of files you want to delete into a text directory.  Make sure one of the following is true:

Option #1: The filenames contain full path.  For example the file might contain:

```
/home/doneill/music/weird_al/duped_file.mp3
/home/doneill/music/weird_al/another_dupe.mp3
/home/doneill/music/bach/baroque_dupe.mp3
```

Option #2: The filenames contain relative path, and the file with the list of filenames is saved in the parent folder.  For example, if your file list was saved in `/home/doneill/music/`, it would contain:

```
weird_al/duped_file.mp3
weird_al/another_dupe.mp3
bach/baroque_dupe.mp3
```

In either case, open up a terminal window, and change to the folder that contains the file with the list  `cd /home/doneill/music/` for example.

Type in:

```
for a in `cat filelist.txt`; do echo $a; done
```

(Replacing filelist.txt with the name of the file with the list).  This should spit out a list of all the files you want to delete.  Take a moment to double check the list.  If it is right, type:

```
for a in `cat filelist.txt`; do rm $a; done
```

This basically tells your computer:  for each line in the file `filelist.txt`, remove a file with the name listed.

Comment: The question asks about duplicate files, no mention of Banshee.

Comment: @jpd It's tagged banshee...

Comment: Sorry, completely missed the tags.

Comment: I can't get to the banshee data base because 11.10 doesn't have the option to open with a custom [command](http://askubuntu.com/questions/67382/add-custom-command-in-the-open-with-dialog) and the workaround suggested there didn't work - I got thrown down the rabbit hole there for a second but I'm back with no solution.

Comment: @JohnMcKeanPruitt 1) Run the sqlite database browser (the command is `sqlitebrowser` if it isn't put into your menu when you install it).  2) File -> Open.  3) Type `/home/[user]/.config/banshee-1/` into the 'Look in' address bar (replace [user] with your username).  4) Double click on `banshee.db`.

Comment: @DavidOneill Great! I got the list. But still I'll have to manually delete the Duplicates :( which will be a long long task, unless I can get some computing power to do it for me.

Comment: @JohnMcKeanPruitt Editing this into my answer - it's a bit long for a comment.